# $sort when updating subdoc array?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

So, `$sort` works with `$push` but is there a way to make it work with `.update()` so that the array can be re-sorted if necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Can you please take a look at these docs and let me know if that answers your question:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/push/
Please let me know if you need anything else.
Best,
Charlie

Comment: The documentation says that `$sort` only works when preceded by `$each` in a `$push`. However, in the scenario where I only need to push a single comment, how can I maintain the pre-sorted order I desire for read queries? In this case, retrieving the last 5 comments and querying for older comments as client paging requests come in.